Using adjustedCurve package after multiple imputation - error: arguments of zero length and no non-missing arguments to max
I am having some issues creating adjusted cumulative incidence function using Kaplan Meier estimator after mice. I repeatedly get an error and, being fairly new to R, I am not sure what it means.
When I run the below code I get the following error:

#IPTW KM using WeightIt on each imputed dataset
install.packages("adjustedCurves")


treatment_model <- with(data=imp, exp=glm(pe ~edu_cat + bmi_cat + mbr_gdm + p_inpatient 
                       + year_cat + age_cat + smoke, family="binomial"(link="logit"), subset=(pop==1) ))

adj<- adjustedsurv(data=imp,
                   variable="pe",
                   ev_time= "timetoprimary",
                   event="egfr59",
                   method = "iptw_km",
                   treatment_model = treatment_model,  
                   conf_int=TRUE,
                   bootstrap=FALSE)

Error in if (est == "surv" & last_est == 0) { : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In max(time_vec) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf


Here is a sample dataset
droplevels(data[1:4, ])
# A tibble: 4 × 102
      pin p_date     b_date     ga_weeks preg_no female dob        dodsdat migr_date
    <dbl> <date>     <date>        <dbl> <fct>   <fct>  <date>     <date>  <date>   
1 1000013 2005-05-02 2006-01-23       38 1       1      1961-10-01 NA      NA       
2 1000018 2018-04-21 2019-01-26       40 1       1      1990-08-01 NA      NA       
3 1000019 2017-07-02 2018-04-08       40 1       1      1984-04-01 NA      NA       
4 1000044 2015-06-04 2016-02-25       38 1       1      1984-02-01 NA      NA       
# ℹ 93 more variables: egfr_baseline <dbl>, albu_baseline <dbl>, egfr59_date <date>,
#   egfr <fct>, albu_date <date>, a_cat <fct>, b_year <dbl>, b_age <dbl>, origin <fct>,
#   edu <fct>, weight_kg <dbl>, length_cm <dbl>, bw_grams <dbl>, sga <fct>,
#   smoke <fct>, parity <fct>, mbr_dm <fct>, mbr_gdm <dbl>, mbr_ht <fct>,
#   mbr_sle <fct>, mbr_glom <fct>, mbr_tbi <fct>, mbr_ckd <fct>, mbr_ckd_glom <fct>,
#   mbr_ckd_other <fct>, mbr_ckd_sec <fct>, mbr_ckd_uns <fct>, mbr_ckd_self <fct>,
#   mbr_pe <fct>, p_pe <fct>, p_pe_date <date>, p_dm <fct>, p_ht <fct>, p_sle <fct>, …


Thank you
I am not sure what is causing this and would appreciate your help/insights.
My ev_time is a numeric variable in days.

I am the developer of this package. Please open an issue at https://github.com/RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves/issues and add a reproducible example. I will then gladly look into this!
